# How to merge two files into one text file?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to merge two text output file into one text file .

file 1:

```
fin=fopen('d://box1.txt','wt');
fprintf(fin,'   Hello \n');
```

file 2:

```
fin=fopen('d://box2.txt','wt');
fprintf(fin,'welcome \n');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Prætorian how to merge 2 files into one text file ?? but it works with Mac way . if you have alternative one ,that will great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a matlab way of doing it easily. But you can use system commands:

Windows:

```
system(type a.txt b.txt >ab.txt)
```

Linux:

```
system(cat a.txt b.txt >ab.txt)
```

Dont forget to put the path in the files if they are not in your current directory!
This works:

```
fin=fopen('D:\box1.txt','wt');
fprintf(fin,'   Hello \n');
fclose(fin)

fin=fopen('D:\box2.txt','wt');
fprintf(fin,'welcome \n');
fclose(fin)

system('type D:\box1.txt D:\box2.txt >E:\box12.txt')
```