# Merging files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the huge set of text files for eg: 'x1_001','x1_002','x1_003','x2_001','x2_002','x2_003','x3_001','x3_002','x3_003'.
I want to merge the files 'x1_001','x2_001','x3_001' together. Similarly: 'x1_002','x2_002','x3_002' and so on.. Finally need to plot a graph for the merged files.
How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to simply concatenate the files, or do you want the data from the different files sorted in some way (merged)? What OS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219140/how-to-merge-two-files-into-one-text-file

Comment: Check the question I linked above and see if the answer there solves your problem.

Comment: no. this is completely static. Cant' it be done in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 3):

You can open up one of the files, copy it line-by-line into a new file until you're done, then open the next file, copy it line-by-line, etc. until you've gone through all of them.

Let's say we have two files, test1.txt and test2.txt. The contents of test1.txt are

> test 1 string 1
>
> test 1 string 1

and the contents of test2.txt are

> test2 string 1
>
> test2 string 2
>
> test2 string 3

then if you use the following code:

```
f_list = {'test1.txt', 'test2.txt'};
f_new = fopen('output.txt','w');

for i = 1:length(f_list)
    f_old = fopen(f_list{i},'r');
    f_line = fgetl(f_old);

    while ischar(f_line)
        fprintf(f_new,'%s',f_line);
        fprintf(f_new,'\n');
        f_line = fgetl(f_old);
    end
    fclose(f_old);
end

fclose(f_new);
```

You get the following in output.txt, which is (I think) what you're wanting:

> test 1 string 1
>
> test 1 string 2
>
> test2 string 1
>
> test2 string 2
>
> test2 string 3

Comment: no not really. First i need to combine the data from the files as described and finally plot the data.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "merge" or "combine". And as for plotting, you have provided absolutely no information regarding what you need plotted or in what fashion. At the moment the only advice we can give you is to use `plot()`.