# How to create both accumulated and non-accumulated MatLab diary output

Tags: matlab

Standard diary does not overwrite existing diary output. That's useful. I sometimes want to check my previous results.

But at the same time, when the output is large, it becomes hard to find where the result from the most-current execution starts.

So I wanted to have both files: One with most current output, another with all the accumulated results.

I did

```
diary result_accumulated.out

delete result.out
diary result.out
```

But result_accumulated.out is not being generated.

What should I do?

Comment: You can not write two diaries at once. MATLAB does not support that.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! I think Randy's solution would work but do you know how to append result.out to result_accumulated.out ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219140/how-to-merge-two-files-into-one-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
diary result.out
...
diary off
```

and then append `result.out` to `result_accumulated.out`

Comment: @Randy_Flamini Thank you! But what codes should I write to append it? And where should I put those codes?

Comment: To append: `system('copy /b file1 + file2 fileappended')`